# Getting An Array of Items within the last 24 hours from a given data using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, algorithm, vue.js

I have some given data where I'm to return some set of arrays with just 24 hours using the time stamp in the given array. I tried the code below but it was returning the same data to me again. I hope I'm not doing

```js
const Array_1 = [
  { class_1: 4, HeadTeacher: "Mrs Joe", time_stamp: "2021-09-23 11:31:41" },
];
const Array_2 = [
  { class_1: 10, HeadTeacher: "Loveth", time_stamp: "2021-09-16 15:16:40" },
];
const Array_3 = [
  { class_1: 1, HeadTeacher: "Itunu", time_stamp: "2021-09-22 14:52:32" },
];
const Array_4 = [
  { class_1: 1, HeadTeacher: "John", time_stamp: "2021-09-21 07:07:30" },
];

const result = [...Array_1, ...Array_2, ...Array_3, ...Array_4];

const Final = result.filter((item, index) => {
  return new Date(item.time_stamp - 86400 * 1000);
});

console.log(Final);
```

it right.

Comment: what do you mean by `with just 24 hours`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this code.
I get the result that the date is greater than (now time - 1 day).

```js
const Array_1 = [
  { class_1: 4, HeadTeacher: "Mrs Joe", time_stamp: "2021-09-23 11:31:41" },
];
const Array_2 = [
  { class_1: 10, HeadTeacher: "Loveth", time_stamp: "2021-09-16 15:16:40" },
];
const Array_3 = [
  { class_1: 1, HeadTeacher: "Itunu", time_stamp: "2021-09-22 14:52:32" },
];
const Array_4 = [
  { class_1: 1, HeadTeacher: "John", time_stamp: "2021-09-21 07:07:30" },
];

const result = [...Array_1, ...Array_2, ...Array_3, ...Array_4];

const Final = result.filter((item) => (new Date(item.time_stamp).getTime() > Date.now() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

console.log(Final);
```

Comment: `new Date(new Date(item.time_stamp).getTime() - 86400 * 1000)`....? Why construct the date twice?

Comment: The Returned array should only return the ones that falls to this present time yesterday....It shouldn't return the ones earlier than that @RyanSchaefer

Comment: @simplelife you didn't include that in the original problem.

Comment: I guess a mistake from my part. Apologies for that. 
I guess my question is to return an array of objects with the head teacher name of Mrs Joe and maybe Itunu

Comment: Oh! But is it possible to have past seven days using this your method

Answer (score 0):

I would first calculate the the timestamp for a day ago and then compare the same with the timestamp in the object

```js
const Array_1 = [
  { class_1: 4, HeadTeacher: "Mrs Joe", time_stamp: "2021-09-23 11:31:41" },
];
const Array_2 = [
  { class_1: 10, HeadTeacher: "Loveth", time_stamp: "2021-09-16 15:16:40" },
];
const Array_3 = [
  { class_1: 1, HeadTeacher: "Itunu", time_stamp: "2021-09-22 14:52:32" },
];
const Array_4 = [
  { class_1: 1, HeadTeacher: "John", time_stamp: "2021-09-21 07:07:30" },
];

const result = [...Array_1, ...Array_2, ...Array_3, ...Array_4];

const DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
const aDayAgo = new Date(Date.now() - DAY);

const final = result.filter( ({time_stamp}) => new Date(time_stamp) > aDayAgo );
console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const Array_1 = [
  { class_1: 4, HeadTeacher: "Mrs Joe", time_stamp: "2021-09-23 11:31:41" },
];
const Array_2 = [
  { class_1: 10, HeadTeacher: "Loveth", time_stamp: "2021-09-16 15:16:40" },
];
const Array_3 = [
  { class_1: 1, HeadTeacher: "Itunu", time_stamp: "2021-09-22 14:52:32" },
];
const Array_4 = [
  { class_1: 1, HeadTeacher: "John", time_stamp: "2021-09-21 07:07:30" },
];

const result = [...Array_1, ...Array_2, ...Array_3, ...Array_4];

const Final = result.filter((item, index) => {
    let d = new Date(item.time_stamp).getTime(),
        passedTimeInHours = (((Date.now() - d) / 1000) / 60) / 60
    return passedTimeInHours < 24
});
```

Answer (score 0):

return value of filter function should be boolean
a) if it is true it will return the value or object
b) if it is false it wont return anything

you can try this

```js
const Array_1 = [
  { class_1: 4, HeadTeacher: "Mrs Joe", time_stamp: "2021-09-23 11:31:41" },
];
const Array_2 = [
  { class_1: 10, HeadTeacher: "Loveth", time_stamp: "2021-09-16 15:16:40" },
];
const Array_3 = [
  { class_1: 1, HeadTeacher: "Itunu", time_stamp: "2021-09-28 14:52:32" },
];
const Array_4 = [
  { class_1: 1, HeadTeacher: "John", time_stamp: "2021-09-27 17:07:30" },
];

const result = [...Array_1, ...Array_2, ...Array_3, ...Array_4];

//no of ms in a day - 86400 * 1000

const Final = result.filter((item, index) => {
  return Boolean((new Date() - new Date(item.time_stamp) < 86400 * 1000));
});

console.log(Final)
```